How to use openrewrite to do javax to jakarta package conversion in spring roo generated aspectj(aj) file
We have a legacy project which has spring roo generated aspectj (aj) for the domain objects. These files contains javax import statements. I am using openrewrite to migrate to jakarta ee 10. However only the java files are being converted.

Is there any provision to say consider *.aj file as well as part the jakarta ee 10 migration openrewrite recipe?
Do I need to write a custom recipe to accomplish the same?


We don't currently have a dedicated parser for .aj files, which would be necessary to make reliable type-based code changes.
If you're ok with doing text-based replacements, you could look at passing in rewrite.plainTextMasks to include **/*.aj as files parsed as text, and then use our Find and Replace recipe to update your AspectJ imports.
The next release of the plugins will contain a change to parse .aj files as plain text by default:

https://github.com/openrewrite/rewrite-maven-plugin/commit/f9d1b47ad1e94046ea258c624832b00c8b9d056d
https://github.com/openrewrite/rewrite-gradle-plugin/commit/a077054a05c819e958f363640b28f6d7b5fdb612

I hope that helps!

I have been using the following command to run the recipe. Could you please provide the corresponding command for the version the parse fix is available.
mvn -U org.openrewrite.maven:rewrite-maven-plugin:run -Drewrite.recipeArtifactCoordinates=org.openrewrite.recipe:rewrite-migrate-java:RELEASE -Drewrite.activeRecipes=org.openrewrite.java.migrate.jakarta.JakartaEE10

That's availabe from v5.33.0 onwards, the latest version being v5.35.0 right now.
